# Rails 4 Rescope or Refilter child object on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

There is a `BillingCycle`:

```
class BillingCycle
    has_many :billing_data, class_name: BillingData
    has_many :billing_data_lines, through: :billing_data
end

class BillingData
  has_many :billing_data_lines
end
```

And Here is the `BillingDataLine`:

```
class BillingDataLine 
  belongs_to :billing_data
end
```

There is a place in the code where we would like to simply rescope or update the list of child records something like this:

```
@cycle.billing_data_lines = @cycle.billing_data_lines.where(info_number: @restricted_numbers)
```

But this clearly doesn't work and it spits out this error:

```
Cannot modify association 'BillingCycle#billing_data_lines' because the source reflection class 'BillingDataLine' is associated to 'BillingData' via :has_many.
```

Maybe I'm trying to approach this situation the wrong way, but it would be nice if you could just re-filter/re-scope the child object's records on the fly.  Is there some way to accomplish what is needed?

Comment: That didn't change much.

Comment: Did you miss a `belongs_to :billing_cycle` in `BillingData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create an alias method and overwrite the records if there were restricted numbers:

```
   alias_method :_billing_data_lines, :billing_data_lines
    def billing_data_lines
        @_restricted_numbers ? _billing_data_lines.where(info_number: @_restricted_numbers) : _billing_data_lines
    end

    def restrict_by_number(numbers)
        @_restricted_numbers = numbers
    end
```

And heres how it was called:

```
@cycle.restrict_by_number(restricted_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

In you class `BillingCycle` refract `class_name` argument to string:

```
class BillingCycle
  has_many :billing_data, class_name: "BillingData"
```

or just remove it, cause it doesn't make sense, since your name is the same.

```
class BillingCycle
  has_many :billing_data
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? By setting the BillingDataLines of a cycle to a subset of its previous BillingDataLines, you will only get the result of removing some of those BillingDataLines. You can get the same effect by negating the query, running it directly on billing data lines and removing the parent relationship there:

```
BillingDataLine.
  where(billing_data: {billing_cycle_id: @cycle.id}).
  where.not(info_number: @restricted_numbers).
  update_all(billing_data_id: nil)
```